# Are there different defintions/ interpretations of the phrase "total solar eclipse"?

Tags: astronomy, terminology, eclipse

One total solar eclipse was visible in the United States on [08 June 1918](https://eclipse.gsfc.nasa.gov/SEplot/SEplot1901/SE1918Jun08T.GIF).  Another on [26 February 1979](https://eclipse.gsfc.nasa.gov/SEplot/SEplot1951/SE1979Feb26T.GIF).  Again, there was one just [the other day](https://eclipse.gsfc.nasa.gov/SEplot/SEplot2001/SE2017Aug21T.GIF) (for those that might not have noticed).  Links are from [NASA](https://eclipse.gsfc.nasa.gov/solar.html).

But the media hype behind this latest eclipse has been inconsistent.  On the one hand:

- Discovery networks, especially Science Channel, advertise their coverage as "an event 99 years in the making."
- Wikipedia's home page today has this "In the news" entry: "A total solar eclipse crosses the contiguous United States for the first time since 1918."

On the other hand:

- Disney Channel and its sister networks have reminded their viewers to take advantage of this first chance in 38 years.
- Likewise, the radio station my car radio is tuned to, was reminding listeners of this first in 38 years, even playing a clip from its own news broadcast from the prior one, wherein the anchor signed off saying something like, 'that ends our coverage tonight .... until next time, in 38 years, on August 21, 2017.'

(Sorry, I don't have exact quotes for the last two.)

For my money the correct value is 38 years.  I was there for the one in 1979.  I was only seven, and the thing that I remember most was how our teachers yelled every 10 seconds, "Don't look up!"  But it happened, and it was 38 years ago, not 99.

This left me scratching my head regarding Discovery networks and Wikipedia.  Have they forgotten?  Are their sources that bad?

But then it occurred to me, perhaps the astronomers out there have different definitions of eclipse, and the various outlets are using these different definitions.  So by one interpretation, it has in fact been 99 years since the last eclipse, since for some reason the 1979 version doesn't fit that more strict definition.

How can we rectify these differing media reports?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about whether a statement made by some sources (some of which seems to be hearsay w/o links) are true or not, rather than about physics.

Comment: As a counter-argument to the VTC, do not judge a question by the answers it generates.  If the answer had been that the 1918 eclipse was a special Type X eclipse, and so was 2107, whereas 1979 was just a plain old eclipse without the special X character, then this question would have an entirely appropriate astronomical answer detailing X.  The fact that X (apparently) does not exist does not change that.

Comment: The counter you claim is **not** what you've asked. The question asked is "Is claim X made by entity Y true or is the claim X' made by entity Z true?" This is not a physics question, it's verifying a claim made by someone (which is what [skeptics.se] is mostly for).

Comment: The 1979 eclipse did not sweep across the entire US from west to east. Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the eclipses you reference were classified as total. There is not a differing definition. The definition of a total solar eclipse is rigid and well-defined; it is any eclipse where from  some place on Earth, the Moon appears to *completely* cover the disk of the Sun AND there is not some other place where it can be viewed as an annular eclipse (in which case, it would be called a *hybrid* eclipse).

Strictly speaking, the sources claiming that it was 38 years since the previous eclipse to have totality visible from the continental United States are correct. Anyone else is wrong.

What is worth mentioning is that the 1979 eclipse was only visible for a relatively small region of north-western United States; it was mostly visible from Canada. On the other hand, the 1918 eclipse was visible in totality right across a band of America, with a path very similar to that on August 21, 2017. So it may be that those claiming 99 years meant only that it has been 99 years since an eclipse happened where the path of totality covered a large range of the country and was visible to many people; where it "crosses the contiguous United States" (the words "crosses" and "contiguous" in Wikipedia's statement suddenly seem critically important). They may not have included 1979 because it only crossed a small part of the country, or didn't go from sea to sea. In my books, they're still wrong and should have made a distinction like that explicitly clear, but I can see why they might choose to say it; it sounds more impressive to say "first in 99 years".

Comment: This has to be it.  But (sarcasm on) so unlike the Discovery networks to twist such a subtle detail for the sake of their ratings (sarcasm off).